# Moq: setting up for a method which returns no value

Tags: moq

I'm trying to mock out a call to a repository. I can successfully do so when a repository call returns a value by using Setup().Returns:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.Get(param)).Returns(new CustomObject());
```

However, when I try to do the same sort of Setup for repository calls which return no values, Moq throws an exception and tells me this method was never called i.e.Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times

Precisely, I'm doing this:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.UpdateRepository(param1)); // UpdateRepository returns no value
service.DoUpdate(param1);
mock.Verify(m => m.UpdateRepository(param1), Times.Exactly(1));
```

Note: DoUpdate method only calls repository.UpdateRepository(param1);

Am I not using Moq setup correctly in this instance? Is there a different way to Setup methods which return no value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that DoUpdate actually calls UpdateRepository?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to setup the call to UpdateRepository. Just verify it.

Given these types:

```
public interface IRepository
{
   void UpdateRepository(string value);
}

public class Service
{
    public Service(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public void DoUpdate(string value)
    {
        _repository.UpdateRepository(value);
    }

    private IRepository _repository;
}
```

Your test method could be as follows:

```
const string param1 = "whatever";

var repoMock = new Mock<IRepository>();

var sut = new Service(repoMock.Object);

sut.DoUpdate(param1);

repoMock.Verify(x => x.UpdateRepository(param1), Times.Once());
```

Comment: Best answer IMO! In some cases it could also be a good Idea to check with Verify before your Invocation that it was never called `Times.Never()`. That is useful to ensure only your method is called.

Comment: @ForceMagic `Never()` can be useful; be cautious about too-strict mocks though. You want the freedom to refactor your implementation without fragile tests breaking. In other words, only verify the specific behavior you're testing.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Verifiable:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.UpdateRepository(param1)).Verifiable();
```

Comment: I'm not seeing mock.Expect via Intellisense? (I'm using Moq 4)